# Inconsistent performance with timeit

Tags: python, linux, performance, cython

Edit for clarity: Essentially what I want to know is **what steps can I take on a shared Linux machine to ensure that the performance of my Python code is as consistent as possible?**

---

I am trying to determine the faster of two different pieces of code using the `timeit` module. Unfortunately, the results are so variable that I have no idea which is better.

The two pieces of code here are a) a Numpy function compiled with Cython and b) a C-like function compiled with Cython. They basically generate a bunch of random numbers and bin them into a number (`parts`) of bins. (No reading/writing to disk involved, so that is not my problem.) I run both functions 20 times during the test, and repeat the test 200 times, selecting the best time out of those 200 tests.

The Python code that I am running to test the speed of the two functions looks like this:

```
import timeit

num = 20

repeat = 200

setup = '''import my_cython_code as sc
parts = 100'''

print "pyx: ", min(timeit.repeat('sc.pyx(parts)', 
    number=num, setup=setup, repeat=repeat))
print "c:   ", min(timeit.repeat('sc.c(parts)', 
    number=num, setup=setup, repeat=repeat))
print "pyx: ", min(timeit.repeat('sc.pyx(parts)', 
    number=num, setup=setup, repeat=repeat))
print "c:   ", min(timeit.repeat('sc.c(parts)', 
    number=num, setup=setup, repeat=repeat))
print "pyx: ", min(timeit.repeat('sc.pyx(parts)', 
    number=num, setup=setup, repeat=repeat))
print "c:   ", min(timeit.repeat('sc.c(parts)', 
    number=num, setup=setup, repeat=repeat))
print "pyx: ", min(timeit.repeat('sc.pyx(parts)', 
    number=num, setup=setup, repeat=repeat))
print "c:   ", min(timeit.repeat('sc.c(parts)', 
    number=num, setup=setup, repeat=repeat))
print "pyx: ", min(timeit.repeat('sc.pyx(parts)', 
    number=num, setup=setup, repeat=repeat))
```

When I run this, I get output looking like this:

```
pyx:  0.00450992584229
c:    0.00507998466492
pyx:  0.00416111946106
c:    0.0036518573761
pyx:  0.00330686569214
c:    0.00355005264282
pyx:  0.00322699546814
c:    0.00346803665161
pyx:  0.00327897071838
```

Why is there so much variation? How can I ensure that performance is more consistent? I am running the code on a shared machine with Scientific Linux release 6.6 installed. (I am not an administrator, so cannot stop other people's processes/etc. in order to test performance.)

---

Note: I appreciate that in this case the two functions appear to nearly equally fast, so my efforts may be somewhat misdirected.

Normally I would use a much greater value of `parts`, somewhere in the region of 10000-100000, which makes both functions much much slower (~O(n)). With the larger values, there may be a more significant difference between the two functions - this is what I'm interested in. In this case I am using smaller values for demonstrative purposes, more than anything.

Unfortunately, due to the inconsistent performance, I can't tell which is faster, hence this question.

---

Following High Performance Mark's suggestion:

```
pyx: min:   0.004488 max:   0.008562 avg:   0.005900 std:   0.001607
c:   min:   0.005030 max:   0.005783 avg:   0.005304 std:   0.000149
pyx: min:   0.004416 max:   0.006408 avg:   0.004995 std:   0.000382
c:   min:   0.004878 max:   0.005824 avg:   0.005357 std:   0.000184
pyx: min:   0.004481 max:   0.005147 avg:   0.004721 std:   0.000130
c:   min:   0.005025 max:   0.005717 avg:   0.005277 std:   0.000145
pyx: min:   0.003409 max:   0.004910 avg:   0.004073 std:   0.000508
c:   min:   0.003712 max:   0.005244 avg:   0.004436 std:   0.000497
```

The mean is more stable most of the time but I do occasionally still get weird performance, like the above.

With `num = 1000` and `repeat = 50`:

```
pyx: min:   0.022578 max:   0.036049 avg:   0.026740 std:   0.005088
c:   min:   0.024303 max:   0.029202 avg:   0.027013 std:   0.001051
pyx: min:   0.022904 max:   0.025746 avg:   0.024109 std:   0.000616
c:   min:   0.018185 max:   0.026352 avg:   0.020287 std:   0.002845
pyx: min:   0.016775 max:   0.017728 avg:   0.017132 std:   0.000195
c:   min:   0.018132 max:   0.020774 avg:   0.019203 std:   0.000714
pyx: min:   0.016763 max:   0.017589 avg:   0.017049 std:   0.000186
c:   min:   0.017587 max:   0.021777 avg:   0.018697 std:   0.001005
```

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - I've added one example with mean and st. dev.

Comment: It seems to me that you should use a higher number in your tests.  With relatively low numbers, the cost of actually timing the iterations and other system factors can really start to represent a larger percentage of the overall runtime.

Comment: @mgilson if I run with `num = 1000` and `repeat = 50`, I still have the same problems. 

Either way, `num` and `repeat` will be limited by how long the functions will take to run when I do my proper tests (with `parts = 100000` or so).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark the last example I just posted shows more of the weird behaviour. If this is the best I can do I'll take it, but is there nothing at all that I can do to give me more consistent results?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Actually I'm the only person who is running anything on the computer at the moment. I'm running 16 Python processes with nice 19, and we have 24 cores on the computer, so (in theory) they shouldn't be interfering too much. I guess I could try to freeze them somehow but that doesn't seem like a viable long-term solution (as in I don't want to have to freeze/unfreeze all my processes every time I want to run a performance check) and won't work if other users have processes running (which I am unable to freeze as a non-admin).

Comment: Spend some time watching your favourite process monitor on your machine, see how much activity the o/s engages in while other programs are running: context-switching, network pinging, file system tending, etc.  If the figures you are reporting are times in seconds (so your timings are down about 2/100ths of a second), the variation you see is easily (perhaps not correctly but it'll be very difficult to prove otherwise) explained by background activity.  You're not testing properly.  Use, as already advised, much larger and longer-running problems before making any inferences.